# Node JS Async Promise.All issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to execute an asynchronous routine for a bunch of items in a list that I get from a database, but I'm having trouble understanding how promise.all works and what it does.

Here is the code I'm using right now:

```
/**
 * Queues up price updates
 */
function updatePrices() {

     console.log("~~~ Now updating all listing prices from Amazon API ~~~");

    //Grabs the listings from the database, this part works fine    
    fetchListings().then(function(listings) {

        //Creates an array of promises from my listing helper class 
        Promise.all(listings.map(function(listing){

            //The promise that resolves to a response from the routine
            return(listing_helper.listingPriceUpdateRoutine(listing.asin));
        })).then(function(results){

            //We want to log the result of all the routine responses
            results.map(function(result){
                console.log(result);
            });

            //Let us know everything finished
            console.log("~~~ Listings updated ~~~");
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log("Catch: ", err);
        });
    });
}
```

Right now, the only thing I get in the log is

> ~~~ Now updating all listing prices from Amazon API ~~~

I've tried adding a logging piece into the routine that is called and the routines all run successfully and log what they should, but promise.all.then doesn't execute.

I've tried just doing:

> Promise.all(bleh).then(console.log("We did it"));

and that worked, but when I put a function in the Then, nothing runs.

Please help!

Comment: tl;dr; - you're missing a return before a promise in a chain.

Comment: Ok, had a quick look at the code - you're missing two `return`s. One before your `Promise.all` and one before `fetchListings()`, promises work by return value - if you don't return from a `then` handler it doesn't wait for anything.

Comment: Also, are all the functions you're calling promise-returning functions? You need to isolate your problem further.

Comment: did you console.log all of your isting_helper.listingPriceUpdateRoutine(listing.asin)? did really all of the finish (count === listens.length?)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum your suggestion didn't seem to change my results. The updatePrices doesn't need to return anything, it just needs to log information. I tried putting the return in front of the Promise.all and in front of the fetchListings().then but it changed nothing.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum All the functions in the routine are promise returning.

Comment: @lipp I logged in each routine call and got a response for every single item passed in.

Comment: I faked some functions and your code just seems to work perfectly: https://tonicdev.com/lipp/promise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Promise.all()` itself is pretty simple.  You pass it an array of promises.  It returns a new promise that will resolve when all the promises in your array resolve or will reject when any individual promise in the array rejects.

```
var pAll = Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]);

pAll.then(function(r) {
    // all promises resolved
    // r is an array of results
}, function(err) {
    // one or more promises rejected
    // err is the reason for the first promise that rejected
});
```

Some reasons that `Promise.all()` might not work in your code:

1. You aren't passing an array of promises to it.
2. Some of the promises in the array you pass never resolve or reject thus `Promise.all()` never resolves/rejects its master promise
3. You aren't properly passing callbacks to `.then()` handlers where you should be
4. You aren't properly returning promises from internal functions so they propagate out or chain properly

---

Your example:

```
Promise.all(bleh).then(console.log("We did it"));
```

Is wrong.  You must pass a function reference to `.then()` like this:

```
Promise.all(bleh).then(function() {
    console.log("We did it")
});
```

In your case, the `console.log()` would execute immediately and not wait for the promises to be resolved.

---

In your detailed code are you 100% sure that:

```
listing_helper.listingPriceUpdateRoutine(listing.asin)
```

is returning a promise?  And, that that promise will get resolved or rejected properly?

---

**Note to Readers** - If you read all the comments, you can see that the OP's actual issue was not with `Promise.all()`, but they were getting rate limited for sending requests too quickly to the target host.  Since that should have been propagating a request error back which should have been easily visible, the OP apparently also has a problem with error handling or propagation which is likely in code that was not disclosed here.

Comment: I've checked all the methods in it a few times and I'll check them once more to be sure. I'd paste the whole thing but it's massive and some of it would probably not be cool to put up on SO.

Comment: @user2172205 - You need to either trace through it in a debugger or add a lot more `console.log()` statements to see where it stops executing.  Not much we can do about that other than advise you to troubleshoot the problem using debugging tools.  For example, put a `console.log()` on the first line in the `fetchListings().then()` handler.  Put one inside the first `.map()` callback.  Verify each return result from `listing_helper.listingPriceUpdateRoutine(listing.asin)`, etc...

Comment: Okay, I found the issue, I think, I'm being limited by the API because I used to have the requests in a leaky bucket. Is there any way I can make a delay between each of the items in the 'map' executing?

Comment: @user2172205 - Proper error handling should have shown you that you were getting some sort of error from the requests.  Changing your question to an entirely new question about rate limiting your requests is not really cool here.  You asked this one about `Promise.all()` and we've pretty much answered that.  If you want to ask a new question about rate limiting your requests or using a leaky bucket, you should do a bunch of research on that topic including all the prior relevant questions/answers on stack overflow and then post a new question if you still need help.

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks for the answer. For some reason the errors didn't pop up in my stack so I'll have to work on that.